# spring batch migration from 4.x to 5.x facing unexpected issue while reading JobParameter from ChunkContext

Tags: spring-batch

I have one DTO class as below

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
public class JobDetailsDTO implements Serializable {
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> params;
    
    public void addParam(String paramName, String paramType, Object paramValue) {
        if(params == null) {
            params = new HashMap<>();
        }
        params.put(paramName, new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put(PARAM_TYPE,paramType.toLowerCase());
                put(PARAM_VALUE,paramValue);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

here one example how we are building JobParamter

```
private JobParameters extracted(JobDetailsDTO dto) {
        JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        setDefaultProperties(dto);// loading job properties 
        builder.addString("job-params", gson.toJson(dto.getParams()));
        return builder.toJobParameters();
    }
```

here is my tasklet

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>>(){}.getType();
        HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>> params = gson.fromJson((String)chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get("job-params1"), listType);
        //here its is failing with IllegalStateException because when debug this while printing this statement chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get("job-params") 
        // i am getting this **{value={"failOnNonZeroSkipCount":{"paramType":"boolean","paramValue":"false"}}, type=class java.lang.String, identifying=true}** but expection is **{"failOnNonZeroSkipCount":{"paramType":"boolean","paramValue":"false"}}**
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }  
}
```

can you please help me as we are population more than 200 job parameters due this issue we unable to migrate can any one help? if any more input required i can provide

expectation is **{"failOnNonZeroSkipCount":{"paramType":"boolean","paramValue":"false"}}** instead of this **{value={"failOnNonZeroSkipCount":{"paramType":"boolean","paramValue":"false"}}, type=class java.lang.String, identifying=true}**

its happening with only two fields one the i have given example second is another DTO having having one field.

even i tried to do poc i unable to replicate even. But our project has huge code base i unable to identify this root case

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you shared, the DTO is first converted to JSON using Gson and then passed as a job parameter of type String to Spring Batch.

What you should do when reading the job parameter is getting *the value* of the parameter and convert it back to a DTO using Gson:

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>> params =
   gson.fromJson(
      (String)chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters()
                          .get("job-params1")
                          .getValue() // this is missing in the code you shared
      , listType);
```

Notice the `.getValue()` here, which is missing from the code you shared.

In Spring Batch 5, job parameters serialization has changed, please check: [Extended notation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html#extended-notation).

Spring Batch 5 also added the possibility to use any type as job parameter. So in your case, there is no need to convert the DTO to a String and use a String job parameter, you can use the DTO itself as a job parameter and provide a converter from String to DTO and back to Spring Batch (in order to know how to serialize/deserialize the type). Please check this section: [Support for any type as a job parameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html#support-for-any-type-as-a-job-parameter). I talked about this new feature at Spring IO [here](https://youtu.be/xoPPTawF_vY?feature=shared&t=1259).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering but concern is, if we are adding data structure like  HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> params even i see issue with normal string without any data structure. As we have more than 100 job parameter's it happing with 4-5 parameters only, The same it was working perfectly with Spring 4.x

```
private JobParameters extracted(JobDetailsDTO dto) {
        JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        setDefaultProperties(dto);// loading job properties 
        builder.addString("job-params", gson.toJson(dto.getParams()));
        return builder.toJobParameters();
    }
```

then getting response JobParameter having inside JobParameter in value field;
for example **{value={value={"failOnNonZeroSkipCount":{"paramType":"boolean","paramValue":"false"}}, type=class java.lang.String, identifying=true}, type=class java.lang.String, identifying=true}**

my first concern why i am getting this above one when i have added only once.
public Map<String, Object> getJobParameters() {
Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<String, JobParameter<?>> entry : stepExecution.getJobParameters().getParameters().entrySet()) {
result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getValue());
}
return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
}

I think we don't need to call explicitly getValue() looking at the code its already returning getValue() of JobParameter.

I am looking solution around here :

```
/**
 * Add a new identifying String parameter for the given key.
 * @param key The parameter accessor.
 * @param parameter The runtime parameter. Must not be {@code null}.
 * @return a reference to this object.
 */
public JobParametersBuilder addString(String key, @NonNull String parameter) {
    return addString(key, parameter, true);
}

/**
 * Add a new String parameter for the given key.
 * @param key The parameter accessor.
 * @param parameter The runtime parameter. Must not be {@code null}.
 * @param identifying The indicates if the parameter is used as part of identifying a
 * job instance.
 * @return a reference to this object.
 */
public JobParametersBuilder addString(String key, @NonNull String parameter, boolean identifying) {
    this.parameterMap.put(key, new JobParameter(parameter, String.class, identifying));
    return this;
}
```

how JobParameter object getting added nested.

Here we are not converting DTO to String only converting params attributes of DTO which is of Map Type Object.